# How can I make a read-only non-editable and non-copy-able excel file?

Tags: excel, readonly, privacy

I have an excel file I want to share publicly. I want that others should only be able to read it. They should not be able to:
1. edit it (That I can do by using Review>Protect Workbook)
2. copy the contents of the file. (How do I do this?)

A user should not be able to select and copy the content of the excel document.

Answer (score 0):

Before you protect the workbook, protect the individual sheets. When you use Protect Sheet, make sure you untick the boxes that allow users to "Select locked cells" and "Select unlocked cells"

[image: Protect Sheet]

They now won't be able to select the data to copy it.

Alternatively, save it as a PDF instead!

Comment: This works but now the hyperlinks are not working. Most of the cells that need to be uncopiable also have hyperlinks that link to other cells in the same sheet. Is there a way to do it with the hyperlinks working?